# name : function(){} or function name (){} | ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I am new to ReactJS and as I am learning I noticed that there's a few ways to declare functions such as,

```
MyFunc : function(){
  ///
}
```

or

```
function MyFunc(){
  ///
}
```

I was wondering which one shall i use and why?

Comment: Those two are not interchangeable the way you posted them. In context where first works the second won't, and vice versa.

Comment: The first one is a syntax error, the second isn't ?!

Comment: It's not a react specific

Comment: @the reason react is the new jquery ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a React specific way of declaring functions. It is a javascript way.

```
MyFunc : function(){
  ///
}
```

Would be in an object literal and

```
function MyFunc(){
 ///
}
```

Would be a constructor or general function.

For example

```
const someObject = {
  MyFunc: function() {
    // some definition here.
  }
}
```

and

```
function MyFunc {
  // some definition here. Something like this.name = 'blah'
}
```

> Which one shall I use and why

That would depend on what behavior you would like. With the constructor function notation, you create an object that can be instantiated into multiple instances (with the `new` keyword), while the literal notation delivers a single object, like a `singleton`.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go with

```
function MyFunc(){
  ///
}
```

For more details see refernce: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html